# Is there any possible way to read Access databases on Linux? Python

Tags: python, linux, ms-access

I'm using Linux Mint and I'm trying to connect with database with .mdb extension (SELECT, FROM, WHERE, DELETE...)
I read many questions about same problem which are posted here, but I'm still struggling.
In my Python code I tried to `import csv, pyodbc`
But every time I get this error

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Also I tried with Jython, but it reports me:

```
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

I installed mdbtools but it doesn't work too.

When I tried to install `libmdbodbc1`

```
Package libmdbodbc1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
```

And now I have no idea what to do to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [mdbtools](https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools) quite successfully via Python to extract data and push them to MySQL..just read the docs

Answer (score 0):

Dbviwer for linux works perfectly

Comment: This should be a comment